# How can I put a ring accent below (or inside) a letter in math mode?

Tags: math-mode, accents, matplotlib

I need to put a circle (ring, zero etc.) below or inside a `\Lambda` letter.

I need to do so both in math mode of LaTeX document and in mathtext mode of matplotlib - so my choice of commands is limited.

If I use `\stackrel{\Lambda}{\circ}` then lambda is to small.

`\Lambda\!\!\!\!\!\circ`looks like bad 'A'.

I even have considered to go with upper accent. Results look bad.
In `\mathring{\Lambda}` ring is to small and not centered.
In `\Lambda\ocirc` ring size is acceptable, but it overlaps with lambda (and is not centered).

Answer (score 3):

NOTE: OP indicates this method does not work for his application, because package imports are not allowed.

Nonetheless, here it is for regular LaTeX, in two forms:

(1) Without smaller math styles:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,graphicx}
\newcommand\circLambda{\ensurestackMath{\stackengine{-.25pt}{\Lambda}{%
  \scalebox{.7}{$\circ\mkern1.7mu$}}{O}{c}{F}{F}{L}}}
\begin{document}
Here is \circLambda

$A \circLambda$
\end{document}
```

[image]

(2) Here it is for smaller mathstyles:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,graphicx,scalerel}
\newcommand\circLambda{\ThisStyle{\ensurestackMath{\stackengine{%
  \dimexpr-.6\LMpt+.3pt\relax}{%
  \SavedStyle\Lambda}{%
  \scalebox{.7}{$\SavedStyle\circ\mkern1.7mu$}}{O}{c}{F}{F}{L}}}}
\begin{document}
Here is \circLambda

$A \circLambda \scriptstyle\circLambda \scriptscriptstyle\circLambda$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I am afraid I can not import any packages in mathtext mode of matplotlib, can I?

Answer (score 2):

Without packages.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\Lambdaring}{{\mathpalette\Lambda@ring\relax}}
\newcommand{\Lambda@ring}[2]{%
  \ooalign{%
    $\m@th#1\Lambda$\cr
    \hidewidth
    \raisebox{-.52\height}[0pt][0pt]{%
      $\m@th#1\mskip-0.9mu\nonscript\mskip-0.2mu\mathring{}$%
    }%
    \hidewidth\cr
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$\mathrm{A}\Lambdaring_{\Lambdaring_{\Lambdaring}}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I am arfraid I can not define macros in mathtext mode of matplotlib.
I have tried to unfold the macro to `\makeatletter \mathpalette \ooalign{% $\m@th#1\Lambda$\cr \hidewidth \raisebox{-.52\height}[0pt][0pt]{% $\m@th#1\mskip-0.9mu\nonscript\mskip-0.2mu\mathring{}$% }% \hidewidth\cr } \relax \makeatother`, but all I got is: `Unknown symbol: \makeatletter (at char 0), (line:1, col:1)`
How shall I unfold it properly?

Comment: @abukaj Then you're doomed, sorry.